Filter formula in excel displays part of the table
A table was created on one excel sheet. On the second sheet, I entered the data filter formula from the first sheet.  If you add data to the first sheet table manually, the filter produces the correct result. But after I try to write rows to an existing table, the filter does not see these written rows
import pandas as pd
def data1():

    list_auto = ['nissan','mazda','bmw','lexus','bmw']
    list_price = [100,388,455,555,265]
    col1 = {
        'auto':list_auto,
        'price':list_price
    }

    df1 = pd.DataFrame(col1)
    df1.to_excel('/Users/18m0011/parse/auto1.xlsx', sheet_name = 'home', index=False)


data1()

def data2():

    list_auto2 = ['nissan','mazda','mersedes','bmw','bmw']
    list_price2 = [100,388,455,555,265]
    col2 = {
        'auto':list_auto2,
        'price':list_price2
    }

    df2 = pd.DataFrame(col2)
    with pd.ExcelWriter('/Users/18m0011/parse/auto1.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', mode='a', if_sheet_exists='overlay') as writer:
                df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='home',index = False, header= False, startrow = writer.sheets['home'].max_row)
    print(df2)

# data2()




You may want create a table in data1() and the use the table name in your filter formula. Please take a look at How to create Excel Table with pandas.to_excel()? - Stack Overflow.

Excel tracks the range references, but it doesn't happen when you change a workbook file out of Excel app. In this case you need to modify the filter formula according to the extended data range.
Alternatively, you can modify the filter formula to allow it to detect the continuous range:

=LET(i;MATCH(2;1/(A:A<>""));FILTER(INDIRECT("A2:B"&i);INDIRECT("A2:A"&i)=E1))

This formula allows you to add data to a file without changing anything else.


You can put the filter formula on any sheet:
=LET(i;MATCH(2;1/(home!A:A<>""));FILTER(INDIRECT("home!A2:B"&i);INDIRECT("home!A2:A"&i)=A1))

MATCH(2;1/(home!A:A<>"")) dynamically determines the last row # of the price book range. It allows you to add/remove any number of rows to/from the price book range and don't care about how it is referenced.
LET(i;MATCH(2;1/(home!A:A<>"")); introduces the temporary variable i with the value of MATCH's result which is used further in this calculation.
INDIRECT("home!A2:B"&i) composes the text referencing the price book range and converts it to the reference.

But in general, the problem is that something is superfluous here: either Excel or a Python application.

I don't quite understand how this formula works. And I have the filter on the second sheet

Thanks for your help, but after moving the filter to another sheet and overwriting the file, the result is the same!! Instead of 4 positions, the filter outputs 2

https://i.sstatic.net/8MpWbzqT.pnghttps://i.sstatic.net/KqL7POGy.png)

(https://i.sstatic.net/8MpWbzqT.png)  (https://i.sstatic.net/KqL7POGy.png)

You should not use the array formula (Ctrl+Shift+Enter). Just enter it as is. The array formula limits the output with the number of cells occupied by the formula.

curly braces appear automatically around the formula after overwriting the file. initially, I just enter

It's a problem. I don't use Python and pandas and not able to comment. It looks like pandas is outdated. You need to update it, or select another library, Or redesign your solution.

Most likely, it's about overwriting the file. And what exactly is wrong, I can't understand

It looks like pandas corrects all references and overwrite the filter formula but uses the "old" array formula format.

You can try to overwrite the formula following data2 to "refresh" it.

I meant to add one method more after calling data2 to rewrite the formula. Not manually, of cause.

Yes, the problem is definitely openpyxl. He constantly rewrites the formula into an array formula
